# DXA .NET 2.2.9 Staging website cannot be load correctly. (css and js cannot be loade caused page not show correctly)

Tags: dxa, content-delivery, dxa2.2, .net, 9.6

Environment:  1. Server A:  Tridion site 9.6 + CD + DXA .NET 2.2.9 (Staging site) 
                
2. Server B:  CD + DXA Java 2.2.3 (Live)

Website :  400 example publication, the whole publication published to Staging and Live successed.
the page preview on Staging and Live both correctly.

website:   500 website which I created inherit 400 example publication. (400 publicaiton is parent of 500 website). nothing new component or page. all the content same as 400 website. I published 500 website to Staging and Live environment all successed. then I previewed page on Live site, it shows correctly, the whole page show as expected.

But when I view the same page on Staging site. the page cannot show correctly. css and js cannot be loaded so  the page style showing not as expected. see attched screenshot.

[image]

As checked further, the issue **only happend on  DXA .NET environment** NOT on DXA Java. the configuration should not have problem.
see below DXA site.log trace log when issue happen.
/500/system/assets  folder not exist in Binary folder. (I should say it not be generated.)

Tried all kinds of ways but this issue still exist.
[image: Trace stie.log]

Comment: Obvious first counter-question: did you publish the Site Configuration page from the 500 publication? It's in the System structure group.

Comment: Hi Quirijn, thanks for comment.  Yes, I Published the whole 500 publication which included system structure group.  the same published to staging and live. live environment show as expected. but dxa .net staging environment not works.